# How to write metaData to an Avro file in Java via writeCustomTypeToGenericRecords?

Tags: java, metadata, apache-beam, avro

I am unable to write custom Metadata to Avro files in Java via writeCustomTypeToGenericRecords.

I have the following code that I am using to write Avro files in an Apache Beam pipeline:

```
private <T> WriteFilesResult<String> writeAvroFiles(PCollection<T> pcollection, DynamicAvroWriter<T> dynamicAvroWriter) {
    return pcollection.apply("Write .avro files", AvroIO.<T>writeCustomTypeToGenericRecords()
        .to(dynamicAvroWriter)
        .withTempDirectory(tempDirectory)
        .withMetadata(ImmutableMap.of("modelVersion", MODEL_VERSION))
        .withSuffix(AVRO_SUFFIX));
}
```

The code writes the files without throwing any errors. But when I am trying to read the metadata, I only see the reserved metadata (avro.schema and avro.codec). Can anyone help me with this? Below is the code I am using to read the Avro files:

```
public String read(String inputFile, String outputFile) {
    DatumReader<GenericRecord> datumReader = new GenericDatumReader<>();
    
    try (DataFileReader<GenericRecord> dataFileReader = new DataFileReader<>(new File(inputFile), datumReader); PrintWriter outputStream = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(outputFile))) {
        outputStream.println("Model Version: " + dataFileReader.getMetaString("modelVersion"));
        outputStream.println("Schema: " + dataFileReader.getSchema());
        int recordCount = 0;
        GenericRecord genericRecord = null;
        while (dataFileReader.hasNext()) {
            genericRecord = dataFileReader.next(genericRecord);
            outputStream.println("Record: " + genericRecord.toString());
            recordCount++;
        }
        outputStream.println("Total Record Count: " + recordCount);
    } catch (IOException ioException) {
        ioException.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    return "Successfully wrote " + outputFile;
}
```